# zsh auto-completion shows too many and it's annoying

Tags: tabs, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, auto, completion

I use WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) and installed zsh and ohmyzsh.
The problem is when I use press `<tab>`, it lists too many commands and files. For example,

```
en<tab>
```

and it lists like this.

```
EnterpriseAPNCsp.dll             en-US                            energytask.dll
EnterpriseAppMgmtClient.dll      enable                           enrollmentapi.dll
EnterpriseAppMgmtSvc.dll         enc2xs                           enterprisecsps.dll
EnterpriseAppVMgmtCSP.dll        encapi.dll                       enterpriseetw.dll
EnterpriseDesktopAppMgmtCSP.dll  encguess                         enterpriseresourcemanager.dll
EnterpriseModernAppMgmtCSP.dll   end                              env
en                               energy.dll                       env_default
en-GB                            energyprov.dll                   envsubst
```

However, only the file `env` is on the current directory.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `.zshrc` file:

```sh
setopt hashexecutablesonly
```

This ensures that [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), when searching your `$path` for commands, will exclude files that are not actually executables.